# how to pass list of object from view to controller on submit button using html.beginform

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

The following is my view `collect.cshtml`

```cs
@using(Html.Beginform("collect", "collection", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>parameter</th>
      <th>Minimum</th>
      <th>Maximum</th>
      <th>Current Value</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in ParameterModel)
    {
      <tr>
        <th>@item.parameter</th>
        <th>@item.Minimum</th>
        <th>@item.Maximum</th>
        <th>@HTML.TextBox("Current_Value")</th>
      </tr>
    }
  </table>
  <div>
    <input type="Submit" name="Save">
  <div>  
}
```

Following is my Controller code

```cs
Public ActionResult collect()
{
    var data =db.Collection.ToList();
    return view(data);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult collect(IEnumerable<Collection> lstcol,decimal Current_Value)
{
    //my saving code will be here 
}
```

In above method I am getting Current_Value which is getting accurate
but not getting list of object its getting null

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. You must use either a `for` loop or create a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Collection`

Comment: you have to understand model list binding